# generating set of polynomial ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

I am considering the polynomials $P=P[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ with coefficients in a ring $R$. Consider a subset $S=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\}$ of $P$. There is a map $f\colon P[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k] \to P$ where $f(p)$ is obtained by substituting $p_i$ for each $x_i$ in $p$. I am interested in the case where $f$ is invertible. What are such subsets called? Of course one such is $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$. Does each such $S$ necessarily have size $n$? Is there a simple way to generate these subsets?

Comment: If the commutative ring $R\neq\{0\}$, then $n$ is unique (i.e., yes, $|S|=n$). Indeed, let $K$ be a quotient field of $R$. Then $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]\otimes_R K$ has Krull dimension $n$. (Of course it's false if $R=\{0\}$.)

Comment: Describe such $n$-tuples is equivalent to determine the automorphism group, as $R$-algebra, of $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. For $R=K$ a field, it means, describing the polynomial automorphism group of the affine $n$-space. This is very complicated.

Comment: Ah, automorphisms, thank you! So my subsets are analogous to a basis of a vector space (I will call them here a "basis"). I'm interested in what is known about change of "basis"; is there anything analogous to elementary matrices? (For instance I suspect that $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\to\{x_1+u,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ where $u$ is any polynomial generated by $\{x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ would be such an operation.) And how can you tell if two polynomials are in the same automorphism equivalence class? (For instance if $R$ is integers I suspect $x$ and $2x$ are not.) Any recommended references welcome.

Comment: It's known that over an algebraically closed field, linear maps and automorphisms of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+P(x))$ ($P$ polynomial) generate automorphism. But I think the analogue in dimension $\ge 3$ is false. For reference maybe search "polynomial automorphisms".